# Group Policy: Screen Saver Timeout is not being honoured by some client machines

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, group-policy

I am having a hard time trying to solve this issue. Recently I created a GPO on a Win2k8 R2 domain controller to set the screen to lock after 30 minutes.

The settings are then applied to a security group which contains all the relevant users.

However on some of the Windows 7 Pro machines the timeout is firing after just 4 minutes. I have checked the workstation to see that the GPO is being pulled through correctly (which it is). I have checked the registry settings to see that the GPO has been applied (which it is), I have also checked to see that the power managment is not interferring  with the lockout with its own schedule (which it is not).

[image: Group Policy Settings]

I have ran gpupdate /force on the affecting machines but I am still not having any joy either.

Has anyone come across this issue before or could offer a possible reason why the lockscreen is firing 26 minutes earlier than it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I have figured out what the issue is.

It seems that some client machines are loading their registry and then applying the registry change from the GPO. This is why when checking the system all appears to be well.

However since the change was made after the registry is loaded some machines must be picking up an old default value which times out after 4 minutes.

By simply rebooting the machine, the new setting in the registry is now loaded and all works as expected.

This is odd since some of the settings seem to be applied but the timeout is not on first load.